# How to disable edit button/input mode in showDatePicker flutter

Tags: datetime, flutter

I'm using showDatePicker function to pick a date from the dialog Calendar. It shows an edit icon at the top right (see img 1) to change to input mode  where the user can enter the date as a text (see img 2)

How to block/disable the edit button/input mode from showing at the top right? I want to remove this icon, because I dont want to use it.

Help me thanks

[image: img 1]
img 1

[image: img 2]
img 2

Answer (score 32):

Use `initialEntryMode`

```
final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime(2015),
      lastDate: DateTime(2101),
      initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendarOnly, // <- this
    );
```

Answer (score 15):

For disabling the Edit icon, all you have to set:

```
initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendarOnly,
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no option to disable that feature.
it is the newest feature in flutter 1.17 on datePicker.

You can set `initialEntryMode` to `DatePickerEntryMode.calendar` or `DatePickerEntryMode.input` but cannot disable it. For example:

```
var picked = await showDatePicker(
  initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.input,
  context: context,
  ...
)
```

Comment: I could disable it in the path sourse code in this path C:\FlutterSDK\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\pickers\date_picker_dialog.dart  I commented // icon: entryModeIcon,  and // onIconPressed: _handleEntryModeToggle,    but I think that is not the best solution because in next version of Flutter maybe this file will be updated and remove my comments // what do you think?

Comment: The problem is with input format, I want that text input follow this format yyyy-mm-dd. The problem is that in the begning it show me the date like yyyy-mm-dd, but when the I try to remove the first number it changes automaticly to this format mm/dd/yyyy.
How to set the input format to yyyy-mm-dd in input mode.  Its dont work with Locale('sv'), its work only if I use english 'en'      locale: Locale('en'),

 final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
               locale: const Locale('sv'), // Swedish calander
               context: context,

Comment: Yea, actually it can be done by changing it in the sdk flutter source code, but that is not the right way. because if you want to update the sdk flutter or want to change the flutter channel, an error will appear from the code that you changed or commented

Comment: I have problem with the input mode format, thats why I want to remove it. I mentioned it above if you can help me

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to the Miko's answer, I've just copied all the src code related with the range picker dialog in to the local project file, and manually removed the `entryModeIcon`

Here is the gist https://gist.github.com/RobertApikyan/ee76abf54cd449cbd190ad703bbaf8bc

Comment: Flutter team have fixed the problem with input format. Thanks for help